# MongoImport on debian missing options

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, nosql

I'm trying to use mongoimport to import a jsonArray but it seems that my mongoimport doesn't have that option.

```
aaa@aaa:~/demo$ mongoimport
connected to: 127.0.0.1
no collection specified!
options:
  --help                  produce help message
  -v [ --verbose ]        be more verbose (include multiple times for more 
                          verbosity e.g. -vvvvv)
  -h [ --host ] arg       mongo host to connect to ("left,right" for pairs)
  -d [ --db ] arg         database to use
  -c [ --collection ] arg collection to use (some commands)
  -u [ --username ] arg   username
  -p [ --password ] arg   password
  --dbpath arg            directly access mongod data files in the given path, 
                          instead of connecting to a mongod instance - needs to
                          lock the data directory, so cannot be used if a 
                          mongod is currently accessing the same path
  --directoryperdb        if dbpath specified, each db is in a separate 
                          directory
  -f [ --fields ] arg     comma seperated list of field names e.g. -f name,age
  --fieldFile arg         file with fields names - 1 per line
  --ignoreBlanks          if given, empty fields in csv and tsv will be ignored
  --type arg              type of file to import.  default: json (json,csv,tsv)
  --file arg              file to import from; if not specified stdin is used
  --drop                  drop collection first 
  --headerline            CSV,TSV only - use first line as headers
```

DId anyone get across this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to use mongoimport is to specify database host, port details and collection name and the 'to be imported' file as an optional argument. Example:

```
mongoimport --host ${host} --port ${port} --db ${db_name} --collection ${collection_name} --file ${to_be_imported_file_name}.
```

You may skip --host and --port part if done against server at localhost:27017.